# How do I get an SP return value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have done it before but just can't get it to work, I only want to do a select within my SP that returns whatever, then execute in the code-behind and then do whatever with the code returned.

The C# code

```
protected long getPassword(string EnteredPass) 
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GetConnector"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection();
    dbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("PL_User_Check", dbConnection);
    dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter abc = dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    abc.Value = EnteredPass;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    dbConnection.Open();

    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dbConnection.Close();
    object x = dbCommand.Parameters[""].Value;
    return Convert.ToInt64(x);
}
```

Stored procedure...

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PL_User_Check]
    @User VARCHAR(50),
    @ReturnValue BIGINT OUTPUT
AS

DECLARE @pass BIGINT

--Data
SET @Pass = (SELECT Pass
    FROM dbo.UserPasswords
    WHERE [User] = @User)

SET @ReturnValue = @Pass
```

Comment: Your SP looks to be over-engineered.  Why not simply restrict it to a select query.  Then it should return a Datatable to .net and you can extract the value there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
ParameterDirection.Output
```

instead of:

```
ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
```

Comment: @connersz, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameter in explicitly and then you can query the parameter object for its value. You are using Parameters.Add and implicitly creating the object. Method:

1. Create parameter object for return value
2. Add to the dbCommand explicitly

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

before execute

```
dbCommand.AddOutParameter("@ReturnValue", DbType.Int64);
```

after execute

```
dbCommand.GetParameterValue<Int64>("@ReturnValue")
```

Comment: On GetParameterValue I get an error: does not contain a definition for 'getparametervalue'

Comment: Same thing for AddOutParameter